# FadeOut all id's with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my HTML:

```
                <div class="content-box" id="enabled_add"> 
                <h2 class="title">hallo</h2>
                <div class="content-box-heading-orange"></div> 
                <div class="content-box-content">
                Hallo
                </div> 
            </div>              
            <div class="content-box" id="enabled_add"> 
                <h2 class="title">hallo2</h2>
                <div class="content-box-heading-orange"></div> 
                <div class="content-box-content">
                Hallo2
                </div> 
            </div>
```

This is my JS

```
$('#usernav_close').click(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#enabled_add').fadeOut('slow');
            });
        });
```

I want to get all of the content-boxes with the id `enabled_add` to FadeOut.
But my problem is that only the first element is selected.

Comment: you can not have multiple elements with the same id, that is your problem

Answer (score 2):

`id`s must be unique. If you try to reuse an id, only the first will be found/updated by jQuery. You want to use a class here.

```html
<div class="content-box enabled_add"> 
  <h2 class="title">hallo</h2>
  <div class="content-box-heading-orange"></div> 
  <div class="content-box-content">
    Hallo
  </div> 
</div>              
<div class="content-box enabled_add"> 
  <h2 class="title">hallo2</h2>
  <div class="content-box-heading-orange"></div> 
  <div class="content-box-content">
    Hallo2
  </div> 
</div>
```

```js
$('#usernav_close').click(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.enabled_add').fadeOut('slow');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The id attribute is supposed to be unique to an element on a page. You aren't supposed to use the same id twice in one document.

[The difference between ids and classes](http://ryanfait.com/articles/the-difference-between-ids-and-classes/)

You can however give an element more than one class.

`<div class="content-box enabled_add">`

That would mean your selector would read

```
$('.enabled_add')
```